# DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#

how to set a data source to a specific cell of a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Answer (score 1):

> Setting the column DataSource,
>   DisplayMember, and ValueMember
>   properties automatically sets the
>   corresponding properties of all cells
>   in the column including the
>   CellTemplate. To override these
>   property values for specific cells,
>   set the column property first, and
>   then set the cell properties.

see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.aspx)
hope this helps...